# Summation of an Arithmetico-Geometric Progression

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus, arithmetic-progressions, geometric-series

$$ \sum_{r=1}^{11} r5^r = \frac{43\times5^{a}+ 5}{b}$$

#### Find (a+b)

This question was asked in an exam. I got the answer 28. However the answer given was 15.
Here is my attempt:
Let S = $ \sum_{r=1}^{11} r5^r $
So, S = $5^1 + 2\cdot5^2 + 3\cdot5^3 + 4\cdot5^4... + 11\cdot5^{11}$ - (i)
$5S$ = $\hspace{1.5cm} 5^2 + 2\cdot5^3 + 3\cdot5^4 + ... + 10\cdot5^{11}+ 11\cdot5^{12}$ - (ii) 
Subtracting (ii) from (i), 
$-4S$ = $5^1 + 5^2 + 5^3 + ... + 5^{11} - 11\cdot5^{12}$ 
$-4S$ = $\frac{5(5^{11} - 1)}{4} - 11\cdot5^{12}$ - (Applied Formula for Sum of GP)
$4S$ = $11\cdot5^{12} - \frac{5(5^{11}-1)}{4}$
$S$ = $\frac{44\cdot5^{12}-5(5^{11}-1)}{16}$
$S$ = $\frac{44\cdot5^{12}-5^{12}+5}{16}$
So, $S$ = $\frac{43\cdot5^{12}+5}{16}$
Hence, a+b = 12+16 = 28.

I cannot point out where am I wrong. Can anyone pointout where have I gone wrong?

Comment: I do not see anything wrong in your argument.

Comment: Just to confirm it [numerically](https://www.wolframalpha.com/input?i=Sum%5Bn*%285%5En%29%2C%7Bn%2C+1%2C+11%7D%5D-%2843*5%5E12%2B5%29%2F16)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your method is fine, here is another:

For $x\neq 0,1$ let set $f(x)=\sum\limits_{r=0}^n x^r=\dfrac{x^{n+1}-1}{x-1}$

$f'(x)=\sum\limits_{r=1}^n rx^{r-1}=\dfrac 1x\sum\limits_{r=1}^n rx^r$

Therefore we find the general formula:

$$\sum\limits_{r=1}^n rx^r=xf'(x)=\frac{(nx-n-1)x^{n+1}+x}{(x-1)^2}$$

Applying for $n=11$ and $x=5$ we find $\sum\limits_{r=1}^{11} r5^r=\dfrac{(55-11-1)5^{12}+5}{(5-1)^2}=\dfrac{43\cdot5^{12}+5}{16}$