# Find the generating function for $a_n=\sum_{k=0}^{n} 3^{k}(n-k), n\geq0$.

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, generating-functions

For every integer $n\geq 0$ we define

$a_n=\sum_{k=0}^{n} 3^{k}(n-k)$.

Find the generating function of the sequence $(a_n)_{n=0}^\infty$ and write down the answer without series.

Attempt: $G(x)=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (\sum_{k=0}^{n} 3^{k}(n-k))x^n=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (n\sum_{k=0}^{n} 3^{k}-\sum_{k=0}^{n}k3^k)x^n=\sum_{n=0}^{\infty}(\frac{1}{2}n(3^{n+1}-1)-\sum_{k=0}^{n}k3^{k})=...?$

where I took into account that $1+3+...+3^n=\frac{1}{2}(3^{n+1}-1)$. How to continue?

WolframAlpha returns: $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} (\sum_{k=0}^{n} 3^{k}(n-k))x^n$=$-\frac{x}{(x-1)^2 (3x-1)}$. How do I get to this?

Comment: What do you mean by "without using series"?

Comment: Also, do you know how to find $\sum k3^k$ (think of derivatives)

Comment: how do i do it with derivatives?

Comment: What is the derivative of $f(x) = \sum_{k=0}^n x^k = \frac{x^{n+1}-1}{x-1}$?

Comment: $f'(x)=\sum_{k=0}^{n} kx^{k-1}$=to what on the right side?

Comment: On the RHS you have $\frac{x^n(nx-n-1)+1}{(x-1)^2}$ using the quotient rule. Now multiply both sides by $x$, and put $x=3$.

Comment: I get $\sum_{k=0}^{n} kx^{k}$=$\frac{3}{4} (2*3^n n - 3^n + 1)$

Comment: Good, now you have an explicit form for $a_n$. Plug everything back, and employ the same trick for sums of the form $\sum nx^n$.

Comment: After you're done, consider answering your own question using the button below.

Comment: so, i get two geometric series, but how do i calculate $\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} nx^n$

Comment: The sums converge iff $|x|<1/3$

Comment: @Sahaj yes, figured it

Comment: @ŽanPeter use the same trick I mentioned

Comment: The derivative trick? But I don't have a finite serie.

Comment: So what? $\sum_{k=0}^\infty x^k = \frac 1{1-x}$.

Comment: @ŽanPeter you might be interested in this [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4744876/summation-of-an-arithmetico-geometric-progression) post and many others which have been posted here time and again.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

We can directly see that $a_n$ is the convolution of the sequences $b_n = 3^n$ and $c_n = n$.  Therefore, the generating function for $a_n$ is the product of the generating functions for $b_n$ and $c_n$, which are $\frac{1}{1-3x}$ and $\frac{x}{(1-x)^2}$, respectively.

Answer (score 3):

The convolution approach by @DanielSchepler is the simplest way, but here is an explicit derivation that does not rely on recognizing that.
\begin{align}
\sum_{n=0}^\infty \sum_{k=0}^n 3^k(n-k) x^n
&= \sum_{k=0}^\infty \sum_{n=k}^\infty 3^k(n-k) x^n \\
&= \sum_{k=0}^\infty (3x)^k \sum_{n=k}^\infty (n-k) x^{n-k} \\
&= \sum_{k=0}^\infty (3x)^k \sum_{n=0}^\infty n x^n \\
&= \sum_{k=0}^\infty (3x)^k \frac{x}{(1-x)^2} \\
&=  \frac{x}{(1-x)^2} \sum_{k=0}^\infty (3x)^k \\
&=  \frac{x}{(1-x)^2} \cdot \frac{1}{1-3x} \\
&=  \frac{x}{(1-x)^2 (1-3x)}
\end{align}

Essentially the same steps yield the general convolution result:
\begin{align}
\sum_{n=0}^\infty a_n x^n
&= \sum_{n=0}^\infty \sum_{k=0}^n b_k c_{n-k} x^n \\
&= \sum_{k=0}^\infty \sum_{n=k}^\infty b_k c_{n-k} x^n \\
&= \sum_{k=0}^\infty b_k x^k \sum_{n=k}^\infty c_{n-k} x^{n-k} \\
&= \sum_{k=0}^\infty b_k x^k \sum_{n=0}^\infty c_n x^n \\
&= \sum_{k=0}^\infty b_k x^k C(x) \\
&=  C(x) \sum_{k=0}^\infty b_k x^k \\
&=  C(x) B(x)
\end{align}

Comment: Could you explain why the first equality applies in the first part of the explanation or the second equality in the second part of the explanation?

Comment: $$\sum_{n\ge 0}\sum_{k=0}^n=\sum_{n,k:0\le k\le n}=\sum_{k\ge 0}\sum_{n\ge k}$$

Answer (score 1):

An alternative method to the discussion in the comments:
We can reindex the sum as follows:
$$\begin{align}\sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \left(\sum_{k=0}^{n} 3^{k}(n-k)\right)x^n &= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \left(\sum_{k=0}^{n} 3^{n-k}k\right)x^n \\
&= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} 3^n\left(\sum_{k=0}^{n} (1/3)^kk\right)x^n \\
&= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} 3^n\left(\frac{3^{n+1} - 2n-3}{4\cdot 3^n}\right)x^n \\
&= \sum_{n=0}^{\infty} \frac{3^{n+1} - 2n-3}{4}x^n 
\end{align}$$
To avoid long calculations (I'm too lazy for this), I leave the rest to the OP. When you split it into three sums, two should be standard GP, the remaining one can be salvaged by using derivatives.